# Unable to attach to remote geth: Invalid pipe address '/.rinkeby/geth.ipc'

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

I'm on Windows trying to connect to Ethereum Testnet via rinkeby.

I downloaded geth 1.8.2 and Ethereum Wallet 0.9.3

I gave 1st command as:

> geth --rinkeby --fast --cache=1024

NOTE: after above command, I get the url on cmd as:

> url=\\.\pipe\geth.ipc

And 2nd command in another command prompt as:

> geth --datadir=./rinkeby attach

The same commands were working earlier.

I uninstalled both geth and Ethereum wallet and installed latest versions. I tried the commands on the earlier versions also where they were working but now they are not.

**I also tried connecting to Private net just now, but got the error message on 2nd command prompt as:**

> Unable to attach to remote geth: no known transport for URL scheme "c"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this issue only occurs on Windows.
Refer: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15746

Try the following to specify the IPC path

```
geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

It should work on Win10 and v1.8.x-stable

Comment: Thanks! Working now for Private net. But still have to try for the Test net.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, same error message:  Invalid pipe address '\.pipegeth.ipc'.